# Insert empty textbox as NULL in database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

If the texbox is empty i want to insert in database NULL.
I have 2 text box name : txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3 and this code :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ALEX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Asig;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand cmd;

.................

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO asigpag( Data1,Data2,Data3 ) VALUES ('" + txtBox1.Text + "','"  + txtBox2.Text + "','" + txtBox3.Text + "')",con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Succes ! ");
```

This correctly inserts data in the database for all three textboxe. But if one of the textboxes is empty, in the database it appears as an empty field instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `TextBox.Text` for empty strings

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO asigpag ( Data1,Data2,Data3 ) VALUES (" + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox1.Text) ? "'" + txtBox1.Text + "'" : "NULL") + "," + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox2.Text) ? "'" + txtBox2.Text + "'" : "NULL") + "," + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox3.Text) ? "'" + txtBox3.Text + "'" : "NULL") + ")",con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ALEX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Asig;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand cmd;

.................

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO asigpag( Data1,Data2,Data3 ) VALUES ('" + 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox1.Text) ? null : txtBox1.Text +  "','"  +
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox2.Text) ? null : txtBox2.Text + "','" + 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox3.Text) ? null : txtBox3.Text + "')",
    con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Success!");
```

Comment: i havent seen bellowed post. when i was typing this was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO asigpag( Data1,Data2,Data3 ) VALUES (" + GetDbValue(txtBox1.Text) + ", "  + GetDbvalue(txtBox2.Text) + " , " + GetDbValue(txtBox3.Text) + ")",con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Succes ! ");


private String GetDbValue(String data)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data)
        return "NULL";
    else
        return "'" + data + "'";
}
```

---

You are using very wrong way to insert data into the database, please consider using paramatrized query.

Your query is vulnerable to `Sql Injection`

Answer (score 0):

you can add condition over there like this:

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO asigpag( Data1,Data2,Data3 ) VALUES ('" + txtBox1.Text==""?"null":txtBox1.Text +     "','"  + txtBox2.Text==""?"null":txtBox2.Text + "','" + txtBox3.Text==""?"null":txtBox3.Text + "')",con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Succes ! ");
```

or check this on

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/671726/Inserting-null-value-into-database-from-textbox-us

Answer (score 0):

This will check the text boxes and then insert a DBNull if the box is empty. It is also paramaterised to avoid injection.
It's also worth taking a look at using statements for your connection and command, there's a good example here http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldatareader

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ALEX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Asig;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand cmd;
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO asigpag( Data1,Data2,Data3 ) VALUES ('@textBox1','@textBox1','@textBox1')",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox1.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox2.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox3", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox3.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtBox3.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Succes ! ");
```